# How does one draw pixels in an OSX application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a file representing pixel data - it is in a custom format, so I need to read the individual bytes that represent the RGB data for each pixel that make up the image. I know how to do this.

What Class do I use which would let me specify the individual pixels that make up the image, and then let me render it in a window of the app

I assume that there is some kind of "Image" object, in which I could specify the individual pixels?

Here is what I think I need to do:
1. In Xcode create a Cocoa application.
2. Then in the window that's created by default, I must be able to add some kind of "view" in which I can render the "image".
3. In that "image", I should be able to specify the RGB values for each pixel in the rectangle representing the "image".

Where do I begin? I am comfortable coding with Objective-C, but I've never written an App with a UI, or where I had to write custom drawing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bytes are in a format recognized by CoreGraphics you can simply read the bytes into a buffer like NSData and create a bitmap image from that. This image you than can display. For example:

```
unsigned char *fftFrames = (unsigned char *) [imageData bytes]; // data from a FFT operation on sound; grayscale in original; i want color.

unsigned char *imgData[3];
imgData[0] = &fftFrames[(int)start];
imgData[1]=imgData[0]+((int)width*(int)height);
imgData[2]=imgData[1]+((int)width*(int)height);

NSBitmapImageRep *sonagramImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:imgData 
    pixelsWide:*size 
    pixelsHigh:height
    bitsPerSample:8
    samplesPerPixel:3
    hasAlpha:NO
    isPlanar:YES
    colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
    bytesPerRow:width bitsPerPixel:8];
```

In the above example the data comes as grayscale from a fft operation, i then duplicate the original data to fill red, green and blue to do some nice CIFilter stuff later on. In the end I get an image like this: http://www.ecoobs.com/img/her-bcAn2-Ft3.png (the brightly colored image in the left window is produced that way, called a sonagram).

it is directly drawn into an `NSView`.

This above is only one way. It can be done very similarly using Quartz. The approach is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're doing up there. My file is in a custom format, so I've managed to create an NSArray of (RGB) triplets. Is there a way I can create an Image by specifying the color of each pixel?

Comment: don't create an `NSArray`, but read your data in one c-array and use that as data for the image creation. Like above in my example, where I use an `unsigned char` array holding my rgb values (integers from 0 to 255). This array specifies first red, then green and then blue for each pixel (rows and columns just chained together)

Comment: I already have the NSArray, but I can copy it to the C-Array. But how do I specify RGB values in the C-Array?

Comment: depending on the image format specify them as unsigned integers or floats and adjust the parameters of initWithBitmapDataPlanes:... for example r 0, g 0 and b 0 is black while r 255, g 255 and b 255 is white (or vice versa, sometimes I mix this up). A color is created by a certain amount of each color component.

Comment: I understand how the colours are made up. My question is, in the array, how do you specify the colours ? For example, does each cell in the array contain a struct containing all three colors, or does each cell contain a colour component ?

Comment: each array is for one color, a single value per pixel. the colors can be either planar or meshed, also [see Apple on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsbitmapimagerep_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/initWithBitmapDataPlanes:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:bitsPerSample:samplesPerPixel:hasAlpha:isPlanar:colorSpaceName:bitmapFormat:bytesPerRow:bitsPerPixel:).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at NetPBM, you could easily convert your data to NetPBM format, and then use any program you like to render it or convert to other formats.

Documentation [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html).

Here is a sample file for a 4x image - as you can see it is ASCII and easy to read/write:

```
P3
# feep.ppm
4 4
15
0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0   15  0 15
0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0    0  0  0
0  0  0    0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0
15  0 15    0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0
```